# Changing cell color based on date from another cell in another tab, on the smae google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

#So, I have 2 tabs, on one tab, is a "Server List" tab and the other tab "Hard Drives"

On the HARD DRIVES tab is a list of hard drives, with ID numbers and warranty expiration Date.

On the SERVER tab, I have cells that have to display the ID of the hard drive.

I want to display on the SERVERS tab in the cells, the ID of a hard drive and also to change color from  white to red, based on the proximity of the expiration date.

Any thoughts or help is appreciated.

I can't seem to figure it out with conditional formatting.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75068577/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: If you share a sample and what you've tried we'll be able to help you more. A starting thing I'll tell you is that you're not supposed to use references from other sheets in Conditional Formatting BUT you can do it with INDIRECT

Comment: I think it would be better if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your spreadsheet so that we can check how you are working with the data and have a better understanding of what you need to accomplish.